# The monotone of an integral function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, approximation

$$L(p)=8\int_0^{2^{-\frac{1}{p}}}(1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}dx, p\in \mathbb{R}, p\ge 1$$

May I ask if this $L$ function is increasing ot decreasing?

Comment: This is a constant, hence increasing and decreasing!. Did you want $L$ to be a function of $p$ instead?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy oh yes, the variable should be p.

Answer (score 0):

Given $$L(p)=8\int_0^{2^{-\frac{1}{p}}}(1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}dx, p\in \mathbb{R}, p\ge 1$$

Calculate $L'(p)$ using [Leibnitz theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$L'(p)=8\left( 1+(2-1)^{1-p}    \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot2^{-\frac{1}{p}}\frac{\log 2}{p^2}-0=8\frac{\log 2}{p^2}$$

Can you solve the question from here?

Comment: I don't understand, why is the second term $0$ ?

Comment: differentiation of  a constant is 0  thus differentiation of 0 is zero

Comment: But where is the term $\int_0^{2^{-\frac{1}{p}}} \frac{\partial}{\partial p} \cdots$ ?

Comment: read this to understand Leibnitz rule http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIntegralRule.html

Comment: Indeed, if you read this link you will see that there is a term $\int_0^{2^{-\frac{1}{p}}} \frac{\partial}{\partial p}(1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}dx$ which is missing in your answer.

Comment: instaed of downvoting you could have calculated differentition of w.r.t to p $$(1+(x^{-p}-1)^{1-p})^{\frac{1}{p}}$$